# How to use System.Management.Automation

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, azure-functions

I have an Azure function that is supposed to trigger a Powershell script. In order to get this to work I user the System.Management.Automation package. Every time the function gets called, I get this exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=6.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

I have looked at where the path of the Nugget package points and this seems to be correct. I have also tried moving this code from the class library(.NET standard 2.0) to the function itself (.NET Core 2.1).
None of my colleagues has ever seen this before either.

At this point I have been looking into this for over a day and I still don't have even the slightest idea of what I am doing wrong here. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like one of the errors that occurs because the library has a deep dependency on a very specific version of the .NET Core runtime (entity framework is another where only newer versions need to wait for the runtime underneath to update). I see this is using 6.0.4 - let me see if I can repro. In the meantime would recommend calling PowerShell scripts using the Azure Functions PowerShell language support (trigger another function)